# Crashlytics not working in iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have added Crashlytics in my app. I have done everything but I am getting this log below and app crashed .

`[Crashlytics] Version 3.8.2 (118)
2016-09-22 14:43:59.011[63895:5921811] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone5,4, 8.1.1 (12B435)
2016-09-22 14:43:59.018[63895:5921811] [Crashlytics:Crash] Last launch failed: this may indicate a crash shortly after app launch.
2016-09-22 14:43:59.327 app[63895:5921811] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '54e8b466b93940cf89bd52b41a0d48b8' for submission
2016-09-22 14:43:59.328 Yapp[63895:5921811] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report as urgent
2016-09-22 14:43:59.328[63895:5921811] [[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports]] Submitting sync /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3A91E31-5DBA-405A-96F9-AAC22E952ED4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mss.App1/v3/prepared/218E0BFF-D991-407C-89C0-99D593E9DE20.multipartmime
2016-09-22 14:43:59.379[63895:5921811] [Answers] Initialized
2016-09-22 14:43:59.399 app[63895:5921834] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3A91E31-5DBA-405A-96F9-AAC22E952ED4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mss.App1/v3/prepared/1BBF731D-7AEC-479C-81BF-A2EF099CEBAC.multipartmime
2016-09-22 14:43:59.401 Yapp[63895:5921834] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
2016-09-22 14:43:59.406 app[63895:5921834] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3A91E31-5DBA-405A-96F9-AAC22E952ED4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mss.App/v3/prepared/0AB2A25D-7DEC-41E9-82D4-029A754C71B0.multipartmime
2016-09-22 14:43:59.408 Yapp[63895:5921834] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
2016-09-22 14:43:59.412 Yapp[63895:5921870] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F3A91E31-5DBA-405A-96F9-AAC22E952ED4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mss.App/v3/prepared/98B3FCA1-65C8-4296-B925-9F6910306888.multipartmime
2016-09-22 14:43:59.417 app[63895:5921870] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
2016-09-22 14:43:59.421 app[63895:5921811] -[Digits start]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165abf70`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please check all steps which are in my answer. I already integrate Crashlytics in my project before few days & it works fine

Comment: Thank Monika Let me try.

Comment: Monika can you please explain me how to get this filed :- 
click on project target >>   Build setting >>  Chnage value of “Debug information Format” set it to “DWARF with dSYM file”
 click on project >>   Build setting >>  Chnage value of “Debug information Format” set it to “DWARF with dSYM file”

Comment: This option "Debug information Format" is in built. U did not get this option @Mss iOS

Comment: Got  it monika.thanks

Comment: [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]]
but why its having crash in this point.can you suggest me what i am doing wrong.i am follow same steps.

Comment: `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]] ` Add this line at last before `return yes`in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Yes i am add this line before  retun Yes.

Comment: I am using in device not simulator because my app is chatting app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124001/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-mss-ios).